# conflict when changing structure of nested table in dbt

Tags: google-bigquery, nested, schema, dbt

I am trying to get an automatically way to merge a modified table in its structure (e.g., change in one column in nested STRUCT) with the previous version of the table in dbt.
In detail, I am using "on_schema_change = append_new_column" which indeed successfully adds a new column to the table, but it triggers an error whenever a column, especially if in a nested column, has been dropped. This results in manually altering the table in Big Query before proceeding with "dbt run" of the table again.
Therefore, I am looking for a way to automatically detect any structure/schema change and merge the new version of the table with the old one without manually altering it.
PS I have tried with "on_schema_change = sync_all_columns", but unfortunately it does not detect changes in nested columns.
PPS the option of "--full refresh" is not possible as I would want to keep the historical data in the table, and avoid re-working the model whenever a schema change occurs.
Any idea is highly appreciated, thank you!
I tried both "on_schema_change = sync_all_columns / append_new_column" to obtain the merge of the previous with current version of table, but unsuccessful.